# Converting a stream of coproduct to a stream of HList - Shapeless and FS2

Tags: scala, shapeless, fs2

I have a fs2 Stream `Stream[F, C`] where `C <: Coproduct`. And I want to transform it into a `Stream[F, H]`  where `H <: HList`. This HList should contain all members that the coproduct `C` had.

So, essentially, a `Pipe[F, C, H]` .

The fs2 Pipe will work by waiting for at least one of each of the coproduct's members to be pulled, and then once at least one of each are pulled, finally combine it into a HList and output it.

So, it will be used pretty much like so:

```scala
type MyCoprod = A :+: B :+: C :+: CNil
type MyHList = A :: B :: C :: HNil

val stream: Stream[F, MyHList] = Stream
  .emits(List(A, B, C)) // my coproducts
  .through(pullAll) // i want to wait for A, B, C to pulled at least once and outputted 
  .map { hlist => ... }
```

I am very very new to Shapeless, and this is what I could think of before hitting a roadblock:

```scala
trait WaitFor[F[_], C <: Coproduct] {
  type Out <: HList

  def apply: Pipe[F, C, Out]
}

object WaitFor {
  type Aux[F[_], C <: Coproduct, Out0 <: HList] =
    WaitFor[F, C] { type Out = Out0 }

  implicit def make[F[_], C <: Coproduct, L <: HList](implicit
    toHList: ToHList.Aux[C, L]
  ): Aux[F, C, L] = new WaitFor.Aux[F, C, L] {
    override type Out = L

    override def apply: Pipe[F, C, Out] = {
      def go(s2: Stream[F, C], currHList: L): Pull[F, L, Unit] = {
        s2.pull.uncons1.flatMap {
          case Some((coproduct, s3)) => {
            // add or update coproduct member to currHList

            // if currHList is the same as L (our output type) then output it (Pull.output1(currHList)) and clear currHList

            // if not, keep iterating:

            go(s3, ???)
          }

          case None => Pull.done
        }
      }
      go(s1, ???).stream
    }
  }

  def pullAll[F[_], C <: Coproduct](
    stream: Stream[F, C]
  )(implicit ev: WaitFor[F, C]): Stream[F, ev.Out] = {
    stream.through(ev.apply)
  }
}
```

My roadblock starts here:

```scala
    override def apply: Pipe[F, C, Out] = ???
```

and that's when my knowledge of Shapeless exhausts.

My idea is to keep track of all coproduct members in a tuple (Option[C1], Option[C2], ...).

Once every element in the tuple is `Some`, I'll covert them to a HList and output them in the Stream.

(I'll be using FS2 Pull to keep track of the state recursively so I'm not worried about that).

But my issue is that, at the value level, there's no way for me to know how long the tuple will be, and for me to construct a tuple.

Any pointers so I can solve this?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is you can have e.g. arbitrarily large number of the first type elements without any element of another types, so much that you might run out of memory. What should happen to prevent this situation? Storing element in some persistent storage? Dropping elements of each type after you'll gather enough number of them? Something else?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok I forgot about that detail. For my use case, having the most recent element of each type is enough. The previous one can be dropped

Comment: By the way... on the solution, I am thinking about using the `LiftAll` type class, using the `Eq` type class. So `LiftAll[Eq, MyCoproduct]`. Then pass the output of that to the `ZipWith` typeclass. So I'd end up with something like (A, Eq[A]) :+: (B, Eq[B]) :+: ... etc

Comment: Then hopefully I can use those to create a polymorphic function to keep track of my state... I don't know, I'll try it right now though

Comment: In such case, I would use `Ref[Option[...]]` for every element that you have in your coproduct, then check if all elements are present, if so, extract them and create single-element Stream with product, if not yet, then return empty Stream - and put all of that into flatMap. The challenge would be creating that logic for an arbitrary coproduct.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Sorry, I fail to see why use Refs in this situation; I will be storing the coproduct members as a value and use FS2 Pull to recursively update the coproduct members and check if we're okay to create an HList and output that. Updated my question a bit to showcase it

Comment: On each new value you'd be updating some "global" storage of `Option[X]` values (where X = A, B, C) before checking if all of Options are Some. If they are you'd be extracting these values and putting them into HList, which you could wrap into Source.pure(hlist), otherwise Source.empty in a flatMap. If you are using some "global" storage - and from the point of view of lazy, non-memoizing stream something outside of stream used to store these values is "global" mutable state - you should use Ref.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok but it doesn't need to be global with fs2 Pull. it's just like a recursive function. the real issue is how, as you mentioned, once I have all the `Some`s, to convert them into an HList X that is the same as the output from ToHList, L

Comment: Thinking a bit more, as you said, I think it's better to maintain a HList where every member is an Option... so then, at every iteration, we check if we got all Somes and only then convert it into the original HList. I can achieve (at the type level) that using `Mapped[L, Option, L1]`

Comment: So, given a coproduct, say, A :+: B :+: CNil, it becomes (at the type level), Option[A] :: Option[B] :: HNil. Which is great. The problem is, once we get for example B from the stream, how do we update that HList so we can add Some(B) in there?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4s2BnyeB2jA

Comment: @DmytroMitin 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's do it step by step:

- your input will be `A :+: B :+: C :+: CNil`
- you will store somewhere: newest `A`, newest `B` etc
- initially there won't be any newest value
- after finding all values you should emit `A :: B :: C :: HNil`
- when you are emitting new `HList` value, you should also reset your intermediate values storage
- that suggest that it would be handy to store these intermediate values as `Option[A] :: Option[B] :: Option[C] :: HNil`

So, let's write a type class which would help us with it:

```scala
import shapeless._

// A type class for collecting Coproduct elements (last-wins)
// until they could be combined into an HList element

// Path-dependent types and Aux for better DX, e.g. when one
// would want Collector[MyType] without manually entering HLists
trait Collector[Input] {

  type Cache
  type Result

  // pure computation of an updated cache
  def updateState(newInput: Input, currentState: Cache): Cache

  // returns Some if all elements of Cache are Some, None otherwise
  def attemptConverting(updatedState: Cache): Option[Result]

  // HLists of Nones
  def emptyCache: Cache
}
object Collector {

  type Aux[Input, Cache0, Result0] = Collector[Input] {
    type Cache = Cache0
    type Result = Result0
  }

  def apply[Input](implicit
      collector: Collector[Input]
  ): Collector.Aux[Input, collector.Cache, collector.Result] =
    collector

  // obligatory empty Coproduct/HList case to terminate recursion
  implicit val nilCollector: Collector.Aux[CNil, HNil, HNil] =
    new Collector[CNil] {

      type Cache = HNil
      type Result = HNil

      override def updateState(newInput: CNil, currentState: HNil): HNil = HNil

      override def attemptConverting(updatedState: HNil): (Option[HNil]) =
        Some(HNil)

      override def emptyCache: HNil = HNil
    }

  // here we define the actual recursive derivation
  implicit def consCollector[
      Head,
      InputTail <: Coproduct,
      CacheTail <: HList,
      ResultTail <: HList
  ](implicit
      tailCollector: Collector.Aux[InputTail, CacheTail, ResultTail]
  ): Collector.Aux[
      Head :+: InputTail,
      Option[Head] :: CacheTail,
      Head :: ResultTail
  ] = new Collector[Head :+: InputTail] {

      type Cache = Option[Head] :: CacheTail
      type Result = Head :: ResultTail

      override def updateState(
          newInput: Head :+: InputTail,
          currentState: Option[Head] :: CacheTail
      ): Option[Head] :: CacheTail = newInput match {
        case Inl(head) => Some(head) :: currentState.tail
        case Inr(tail) =>
          currentState.head :: tailCollector.updateState(
            tail,
            currentState.tail
          )
      }

      override def attemptConverting(
          updatedState: Option[Head] :: CacheTail
      ): Option[Head :: ResultTail] = for {
        head <- updatedState.head
        tail <- tailCollector.attemptConverting(updatedState.tail)
      } yield head :: tail

      override def emptyCache: Option[Head] :: CacheTail =
        None :: tailCollector.emptyCache
    }
}
```

This code doesn't assume how we would store our cache not how we would update it. So we might test it with some impure code:

```scala
import shapeless.ops.coproduct.Inject

type Input = String :+: Int :+: Double :+: CNil
val collector = Collector[Input]

// dirty, but good enough for demo
var cache = collector.emptyCache

LazyList[Input](
  Inject[Input, String].apply("test1"),
  Inject[Input, String].apply("test2"),
  Inject[Input, String].apply("test3"),
  Inject[Input, Int].apply(1),
  Inject[Input, Int].apply(2),
  Inject[Input, Int].apply(3),
  Inject[Input, Double].apply(3),
  Inject[Input, Double].apply(4),
  Inject[Input, Double].apply(3),
  Inject[Input, String].apply("test4"),
  Inject[Input, Int].apply(4),
).foreach { input =>
  val newCache = collector.updateState(input, cache)
  collector.attemptConverting(newCache) match {
    case Some(value) =>
      println(s"Product computed: value!")
      cache = collector.emptyCache
    case None =>
      cache = newCache
  }
  println(s"Current cache: $cache")
}
```

We can [check with Scaste](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/WW0xVXdeSl2gHs6WE2G4Sg) that it prints what we expect it would.

```
Current cache: Some(test1) :: None :: None :: HNil
Current cache: Some(test2) :: None :: None :: HNil
Current cache: Some(test3) :: None :: None :: HNil
Current cache: Some(test3) :: Some(1) :: None :: HNil
Current cache: Some(test3) :: Some(2) :: None :: HNil
Current cache: Some(test3) :: Some(3) :: None :: HNil
Product computed: test3 :: 3 :: 3.0 :: HNil!
Current cache: None :: None :: None :: HNil
Current cache: None :: None :: Some(4.0) :: HNil
Current cache: None :: None :: Some(3.0) :: HNil
Current cache: Some(test4) :: None :: Some(3.0) :: HNil
Product computed: test4 :: 4 :: 3.0 :: HNil!
Current cache: None :: None :: None :: HNil
```

Now, it's a matter of how we'll thread this intermediate result through the FS2 Stream. One way would be to use `Ref`

```
for {
  // for easy passing of cache around
  cacheRef <- Stream.eval(Ref[IO].of(collector.emptyCache))
  // source of Coproducts
  input <- Stream[IO, Input](
    Inject[Input, String].apply("test1"),
    Inject[Input, String].apply("test2"),
    Inject[Input, String].apply("test3"),
    Inject[Input, Int].apply(1),
    Inject[Input, Int].apply(2),
    Inject[Input, Int].apply(3),
    Inject[Input, Double].apply(3)
  )
  updateCache = cacheRef.modify[Stream[IO, collector.Result]] { cache =>
    val newCache = collector.updateState(input, cache)
    collector.attemptConverting(newCache) match {
      case Some(value) => collector.emptyCache -> Stream(value)
      case None        => newCache -> Stream.empty
    }
  }
  // emits new HList only if all of its elements has been gathered 
  hlist <- Stream.eval(updateCache).flatten
} yield hlist
```

One might modify this code to fit their aesthetics: extract `updateCache` to some function, use state monad or whatever. I guess turning it into pipe would be, e.g.:

```
// you might replace cats.effect.IO with F[_]: Monad, use something
// else instead of Ref, or whatever
def collectCoproductsToHList[Input](
    implicit collector: Collector[Input]
): IO[Pipe[IO, Input, collector.Result]] = 
  Ref[IO].of(collector.emptyCache).map { cacheRef =>
      
    val pipe: Pipe[IO, Input, collector.Result] = inputStream => for {
      input <- inputStream
      updateCache = cacheRef.modify[Stream[IO, collector.Result]] { cache =>
        val newCache = collector.updateState(input, cache)
        collector.attemptConverting(newCache) match {
          case Some(value) => collector.emptyCache -> Stream(value)
          case None        => newCache             -> Stream.empty
        }
      }
      hlist <- Stream.eval(updateCache).flatten
    } yield hlist
      
    pipe
  }
```

Comment: Just amazing, you're a god. No words to describe how thankful I am! Thanks a lot, pretty clever :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to @Mateusz Kubuszok amazing answer, this is how I decided to store the `Collector` cache (fs2 Pull way):

```scala
trait CollectorPipe[F[_], C <: Coproduct] {
  type Out <: HList

  def pipe: Pipe[F, C, Out]
}

object CollectorPipe {
  type Aux[F[_], C <: Coproduct, Out0 <: HList] =
    CollectorPipe[F, C] { type Out = Out0 }

  def instance[F[_], C <: Coproduct, Out0 <: HList](tubo: Pipe[F, C, Out0]): Aux[F, C, Out0] =
    new CollectorPipe[F, C] {
      override type Out = Out0
      override def pipe: Pipe[F, C, Out0] = tubo
    }

  implicit def make[
    F[_],
    C <: Coproduct
  ](implicit
    collector: Collector[C]
  ): Aux[F, C, collector.Result] = instance { s1 =>
    def go(s2: Stream[F, C], curr: collector.Cache): Pull[F, collector.Result, Unit] = {
      s2.pull.uncons1.flatMap {
        case Some((c, s3)) => {
          val newState = collector.updateState(c, curr)

          collector.attemptConverting(newState) match {
            case Some(value) => Pull.output1(value) >> go(s3, collector.emptyCache)
            case None        => go(s3, newState)
          }
        }
        case None          => Pull.done
      }
    }

    go(s1, collector.emptyCache).stream
  }

  implicit class CollectorPipeStreamOps[F[_], A <: Coproduct](private val s: Stream[F, A]) {
    def pullAll(implicit ev: CollectorPipe[F, A]): Stream[F, ev.Out] = s.through(ev.pipe)
  }
}
```